# keyup() event doesn't works on different languages except english on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyup

I am using keyup function in HTML5 app to determine what key is pressed, and then do some CSS work.
I run it on mobile device.If I press english
character it works fine, but if I press Russian character or other language, it won't get into the event.

In my computer's browser(Chrome) it works fine, bug happens only on mobile device...Any ideas?

```
 $('#inputText').keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val())
            //DO CSS
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the change method in jQuery. Assuming #inputText is an input element.

```
$('#inputText').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        //DO CSS
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Another try:

```
$(document).on('change', '#inputText', function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        //DO CSS
    }
})
```

Comment: It's not working.I using jQuery 1.7.2 version, and jQueryMobile 1.0.1

Comment: hmm, you could try $(document).on('change', '#inputText', function() {...}) http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$("#inputText").change(function(event) {
   if ($(this).val())
   {
          //DO something
   }
});
```

Comment: Why would this make a difference? Also, `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed in 1.9

Comment: You forgot a closing bracket in your snippet.

Comment: Thank you Killian and billyonecan. :)